Error uploading appBundle to APS Design Automation
I'm trying to upload the app-bundle to aps, but keeps getting a 404 error:
{
    "developerMessage": "The requested resource does not exist.",
    "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
    "errorCode": ""
}

This is the request I'm sending:
curl --location 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/appbundles/ExtractPlugin' \
     --header 'Cookie: PF=MwJ3X4X7Sz3irbDLEJGGzn' \
     --form 'key="apps/Swapp/ExtractPlugin/1"' \
     --form 'content-type="application/octet-stream"' \
     --form 'policy="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"' \
     --form 'success_action_status="200"' \
     --form 'x-amz-signature="a0b606cd71519983cc9f523c97bb47477abdfe056f30964c71e0f0a862d718d7"' \
     --form 'x-amz-credential="ASIATGVJZKM3N4737O6J/20240405/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request/"' \
     --form 'x-amz-algorithm="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"' \
     --form 'x-amz-date="20240405T120253Z"' \
     --form 'x-amz-server-side-encryption="AES256"' \
     --form 'x-amz-security-token="IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHwaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDGmjNr6MbWKjee9q2oIML6OWybxJwUM/MJQUbPHzIfaQIgLBcknKZZj+34SKhtDumDf2yVSITDWMYDHQsb7UBQOHYqiQMIpf//////////ARAEGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDCkedD5Q/NRtWXBusCrdAohkmjL8BQCoIiBk3YZM2jd8OkflHlXB8uFGiDEFrUxTi7qkp61K78QX+F5DpdmZl0VAcyPRvlrYhN45IZ2g8e1IxRyNdJmjG8kiEMa+oaKIJZbgK7KQT9O6KIic3CL0liskwxAl8PWdAKnV7SvuIyTGPWpMUqH1IZBblkS9kClzdhanWxjwCmP5xu5AfmP5Rprld7Lv1rC8C6Pesc33GzleEXnY+HOPHMu7Nf9hlZ/FEKXd5EbWNBaCizMLv9C8Rrqdb5JbmpjjFFEIOLyaIcobeG5hlX10F69jBMdn3KHFLZ061evxmj9IM7SdVuWipZVSgBHfAtFax5hR0hd8QOLk6S29Pgks6RY0FONB8Q5dQtuEdZNyGi96k09VnkQJO+CBuEbJwSdUpH52vAvTL9tONvJaPEer3K0WJ2tUx4g6utNL2Io5E07uS5dU83ji/uJ7mMjXOTQq21m7+lUwqcu/sAY6ngH9tACzmcc8wW/Uti4WRsBiorpZRyb3TbjtpmCDAXxs7Fv09FcW06cnTFwU6f/vYSI1XI0tI9BlrvQniNT6ncM9c52jzMYR+INwAo/LYj/cc6Bkxhdd8DmVtRzvzeTJn2wH1BKZjPtxP0TFfEwylds2pW9ThKCrZB4gxLgX4RSkmzJm6MFld+zd54PWjD75oLnoFM3fviO/pEW10kayfg=="' \
     --form 'success_action_redirect=""' \
     --form 'file=@"/home/eugene/Downloads/SwappDesignAutomationPlugin.zip"'

I have been executing the upload immediately after registering the bundle, so it is not a timeout issue, and I also do see the newly registered appBundle in list of all bundles:
{
    "paginationToken": "2",
    "data": [
        "Swapp.ExtractPlugin+$LATEST",
        "Clarity.ClarityTaskProcessor2023R23+prod",
        "Clarity.ClarityTaskProcessor2023R21+prod",
        "Clarity.ClarityTaskProcessor2022R19+prod",
        "Clarity.ClarityTaskProcessor2022R22+prod",
        "Clarity.ClarityTaskProcessor2022R20+prod",
        "Autodesk.TestsApp+Latest",
        "3dsMax.UVUnwrap+latest",
        "Clarity.ClarityTaskProcessor2022R21+prod",
        "Autodesk.APSTokenExtenderTestsApp+Latest",
        "Inventor.ChPa+prod",
        "Inventor.Configuration2021+prod",
        "Clarity.ClarityTaskProcessor2023R20+prod",
        "Inventor.iLogicSampleAppPackage2021+prod",
        "Clarity.ClarityTaskProcessor2023R22+prod",
        "Clarity.ClarityTaskProcessor2022R18+prod",
        "Clarity.ClarityTaskProcessor2023R19+prod",
        "AutoCAD.Publish2View23+prod",
        "Autodesk.VarArgTestsApp+Latest",
        "Clarity.ClarityTaskProcessor2020+prod"
    ]    
}


The endpoint was wrong, it should be: https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com for uploading an appBundle
